# Relation between a function and its derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

If we know that $f$ has derivatives of all orders and for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$f^{(n+2)}(x) +af^{(n+1)}(x)+bf^{(n)}(x)=0$$
How can we conclude that the taylor expansion of $f$ centered at any point converges to $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption shows that $g=f^{(n)}$ is a solution of the differential equation $y''+ay'+b=0$. But we have complete description of these solutions. They have the following forms $x\mapsto Ae^{rx}+Be^{sx}$,  $x\mapsto (Ax+b)e^{rx}$, or
$x\mapsto (A \cos(\alpha x)+B\sin(\beta x))e^{\beta x}$, according to the types of the solutions of $\lambda^2+a\lambda +b=0$. So, $g=f^{(n)}$ is analytic, and then the same holds for $f$.

Comment: I like that.  Is there a way to do it without solving for the function though?